# Pandas - Recall Earliest Value for a Particular Group

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data set which looks like this

```
ID        TimeStamp        ScoreA ScoreB  Type       
A         20150908143000    345    316    New
B         20150908140300    400    480    New
B         20150908140600    NaN    120    Old
B         20150908143000  10743   8803    Old
C         20150908140100    600   1715    New
C         20150908140200    200   1062    Old
C         20150908141000    NaN    145    Old
C         20150908141500    418    NaN    Old
D         20150908143000    433     65    New
```

I'd like to have the results look like this

```
ID        TimeStamp       Score1  Score2  Type  FirstScore1  FirstScore2  
A         20150908143000    345    316    New
B         20150908140300    400    480    New
B         20150908140600    NaN    120    Old   400          480
B         20150908143000  10743   8803    Old   400          480
C         20150908140100    600   1715    New
C         20150908140200    200   1062    Old   600          1715
C         20150908141000    NaN    145    Old   600          1715
C         20150908141500    418    NaN    Old   600          1715
D         20150908143000    433     65    New
```

such that whenever the 'Type' is equal to 'Old', then the earliest 'ScoreA' and 'ScoreB' for that particular 'ID' are recalled and placed in 'FirstScoreA' and 'FirstScoreB' respectively.

I've been able to come up with code which gets me the max value, but not the earliest. But even with that, I couldn't restrict it to just a particular ID, so I'm doubly stuck.

Would someone be able to help figure this out for me?

Comment: Could you share the code you've written so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['FirstScore1'] = np.where(df.Type=='New', df.ScoreA, np.nan)
df['FirstScore1'] = df.groupby('ID').FirstScore1.transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
df['FirstScore1'] = np.where(df.Type=='New', np.nan, df['FirstScore1'])
df['FirstScore2'] = np.where(df.Type=='New', df.ScoreB, np.nan)
df['FirstScore2'] = df.groupby('ID').FirstScore2.transform(lambda x: x.ffill())
df['FirstScore2'] = np.where(df.Type=='New', np.nan, df['FirstScore2'])


    ID  TimeStamp       ScoreA  ScoreB  Type    FirstScore1 FirstScore2
0   A   20150908143000  345.0   316.0   New     NaN         NaN
1   B   20150908140300  400.0   480.0   New     NaN         NaN
2   B   20150908140600  NaN 1   20.0    Old     400.0       480.0
3   B   20150908143000  10743.0 8803.0  Old     400.0       480.0
4   C   20150908140100  600.0   1715.0  New     NaN         NaN
5   C   20150908140200  200.0   1062.0  Old     600.0       1715.0
6   C   20150908141000  NaN     145.0   Old     600.0       1715.0
7   C   20150908141500  418.0   NaN     Old     600.0       1715.0
8   D   20150908143000  433.0   65.0    New     NaN         NaN
```